# Asp net Identity 2.0 bearer token and roles errors

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, roles, asp.net-identity-2

How i can doing customize error response when user doesn't have role but have bearer token?

By default Identity 2.0 send identical response when user don't have token and role.

Please say me what methods i must override to solve this problem.

I use Asp net Web Api 2.0.

Request headers:

```
content-type: application/json
accept: application/json
authorization: bearer {token_value}
```

Response headers:

```
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
expires:-1
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
www-authenticate: Bearer
x-sourcefiles:
=?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdCBWUzE3XEJveGluZ0FwcFxBcHBCb3hpbmdcQXBwQm94aW5nXGFwaVxWYWx1ZXNcVXNlcg==?=
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 20:08:14 GMT
content-length: 61
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

Responses is identical when user doesn't have role or token.
Response code is 401

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var roleManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();



            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
               OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);


            String roles = String.Empty;

            foreach (var roleClaim in user.Roles)
            {
                ApplicationRole rol = null;
                rol = roleManager.FindById(roleClaim.RoleId);
                if (rol != null)
                    roles += rol.Name + ", ";
            }

            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, roles.ToString());  


            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

            context.Validated(ticket);

        }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
    [Route("Admin")]
    public String ForAdmin()
    {
        return "Only Admin";
    }
```

Response token:

```
{
"access_token": "{token_value}",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 299,
"refresh_token": "{refresh_token}",
"userName": "{user_name}",
"roles": "Default",
".issued": "Tue, 11 Sep 2018 20:32:27 GMT",
".expires": "Tue, 11 Sep 2018 20:37:27 GMT"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the response is the same? Without token you should receive 401 (Unauthorized) while with insufficient rights (missing role) you should receive 403 (Forbidden). Some code may help to answer your question. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I checked just now. Yes, responses is identical.